# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Invalid WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, tomcat

I get the following error while trying to generate a web-services client stub...

When I log into Apache Admin page and I can see the web service and the service end point of 'http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloWorldService?wsdl' - why cant WSDL2Java.bat find the wsdl file..?

```
C:\AAA\HelloWorld\client\client>WSDL2Java.bat -uri http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloWorldService?wsdl -o client

Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Axis2\axis2-1.5.6
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Invalid WSDL Location
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:58)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:28)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:8080\axis2\services\HelloWorldService?wsdl (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.getWOM(CodeGenerationEngine.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:52)
        ... 2 more
C:\AAA\HelloWorld\client\client>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly exception says, it can not find the file

```
http:\localhost:8080\axis2\services\HelloWorldService?wsdl.
```

Please check if there is any file and run it.